# How can you publish using the ConsumeContext<T>() when using IReceiveObserver

Tags: masstransit

When consuming faults implementing the IReceiveObserver, we are unable to publish via the ConsumeContext.Publish() method? The published messages aren't being received, what could be missing?

```
public Task ConsumeFault<T>(ConsumeContext<T> context, TimeSpan elapsed, string consumerType, Exception exception) where T : class
    {
        // called when the message is consumed but the consumer throws an exception
      context.Publish(new {...});  //--> Doesn't publish the msg

    }
```

To provide some context, we are firing off long running jobs and maintain a job dashboard to view their current status. Process flow is CreateJob->Send JobMessage-> JobConsumer receives and executes the task-> UpdateJob. All jobConsumer faults are being handled appropriately. In order to monitor Bus faults, we are looking to use the observers, so as to handle serialization/configuration errors etc. Aside from logging these faults, would also want to update the job state so that the dashboard would reflect the appropriate state. The IReceiveObserver receives the fault, however we would like to publish it to a central consumer to handle the updates as well. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

For posterity was able to address this by registering an generic Fault consumer i.e IConsumer. As job context was in the message headers further actions were taken appropriately. Thank you Chris Patterson for the "MassTransit Commute - Consuming Fault Events" video!